# Creating IIS Rewrite Rules

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm having a hard time converting old .htaccess rewrite rules to new IIS ones so I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Below are some example URLs I would like rewriting.

```
http://example.org.uk/about/

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/about/about.html

-----------

http://example.org.uk/blog/events/

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/blog/events.html

-----------

http://example.org.uk/blog/2010/11/foo-bar

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/blog/2010/11/foo-bar.html
```

The directories and file names are generic and could be anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotchas:

Match URL only matches after the slash that trails the host - (.*) is common, and becomes {R:1} if you want to reuse the capture.

Host/domain name matches are done using {HTTP_HOST} in a condition. Conditions become {C:#}; multiple conditions can be confusing/complicated, I'm not sure how the numbering works precisely there.

Append querystring is usually a good option.

Looks like you want to preserve your host header, and rewrite host in response headers. The former is a applicationHost.config setting, or an appcmd change; the latter is in the GUI, or again can be touched in the .config file by hand, or using appcmd.